# JSON Syntax: Add rel attribute?

Tags: json

How do I add an attribute rel=blah to a JSON string? I have the following in a JSON file:

```
[
    {"image":"/images/image1.png", "link":"http://mylink.com"},
    {"image":"/images/image2.png", "link":"http://mylink.com"},
    {"image":"/images/image3.png", "link":"http://mylink.com"}
]
```

The output creates the images and links I want on the page. But I've tried to add a rel attribute like following:

```
{"image":"/images/image3.png", "link":{"rel":"blah","href":"http://mylink.com"}}
{"image":"/images/image3.png", "link":{"rel":"blah","uri":"http://mylink.com"}}
```

but the output was always the same: `<a href="object Object">` Seems like a simple thing but I can't seem to find the right syntax anywhere.

The piece of the image scrubber javascript that produces the image/link is this:

```
 setImage: function(index) {
        this.element.empty();
        var anchor = new Element('a', {
            'href': this.imageList[index].link
        });
        this.images[index].inject(anchor);
        anchor.inject(this.element);
        this.oldIndex = index;
    },
```

Comment: This is an issue with the converter.

Comment: Show the JavaScript code that processes the JSON string to produce the links.

Comment: Added above. Part of the code anyway, its part of an image scrubber script, I think what I posted above is the relevant bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question about Javascript, not JSON. You have to rewrite the function, which generates the HTML output, for your new object structure. Now I don't know what you're working with there, but from the function you posted, this is my guess what you have to change:

> ```
> setImage: function(index) {
>     this.element.empty();
>     var anchor = new Element('a', {
> ```

```
         // here it comes:
         'href': this.imageList[index].link.href,
         'rel': this.imageList[index].link.rel
         // that's it
```

> ```
>     });
>     this.images[index].inject(anchor);
>     anchor.inject(this.element);
>     this.oldIndex = index;
> },
> ```

Comment: Yep it seems pretty straightforward now that I get how it all connects:) Thanks for the help - one thing though, I think there needs to be a comma after the "this.imageList[index].link.href"

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, whatever code is processing your JSON is doing the following:

1. Create an anchor tag
2. Create an image tag
3. Set the src attribute of the image tag to the value of `image` in the JSON object.
4. Set the href attribute of the anchor tag to the value of `link` in the JSON object.

However, with the updated code this will not work. You need to do the following:

1. Create and anchor tag.
2. Create an image tag.
3. Set the src attribute of the image tag to the value of `image` in the JSON object.
4. Set the href attribute of the anchor tag to the value of `link.href` in the JSON object.
5. Set the rel attribute of the anchor tag to the value of `link.rel` in the JSON object.

Or, you could just modify your original JSON as follows:

```
{"image":"/images/image1.png", "link":"http://mylink.com", "rel":"blah"}
```

Then, your algorithm to implement would be as follows:

1. Create and anchor tag.
2. Create an image tag.
3. Set the src attribute of the image tag to the value of `image` in the JSON object.
4. Set the href attribute of the anchor tag to the value of `link` in the JSON object.
5. Set the rel attribute of the anchor tag to the value of `rel` in the JSON object.

Comment: Ah, I understand a little better now. The javascript that produces the links is fairly large script creating an image scrubber. The snippet that produces the image and link is added above now.